# How to initiate, increment and set expiration in the same Redis command?

Tags: redis, node-redis, redis-cli

`INCR mykey` initiates to 0 and increments the value to 1. How would I set expiration time to the `mykey` in the same command like it can be done with `SETEX` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use pipeline or a lua script

in fact, in redis documentation, there is an example of implementing rate limit that needs to increase and set ttl using multi

https://redis.io/commands/INCR

Comment: Lua script is better, since it's atomic